# How to jungle with an ADC?

Tags: league-of-legends

After all the recent changes coming with the preseason 5 to the jungle, its mobs, path, and difficulty, is it still possible to play an ADC (marksman) in the jungle that is viable ? If yes, how (items, masteries, runes and path) and especially who ?

To be more precise, by viable I mean a jungle clearing potential close to a normal jungler and/or any gank power (I don't know maybe damage alone is enough).

I ask that as a main ADC/jungler player, that wants to combine both for once !

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which ADC champion do you want tips for jungling? You know, this is a case by case scenario.

Comment: I've seen vayne used in the new jungle. I don't know how good it actually is but in theory impale+silver bolts should help a lot if you start gromp.

Comment: @TheLorderrr This is not about microing, but more about macro, the builds and champions viable. I know the execution to jungle with a distance character and all this. I would just like to know which ADC are able to be played jungle in this season and with what build.

Comment: TF is played a lot in the jungle, its viable and most builds are AS + AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to play an AD Carry in the jungle. There are certain spots for each camp (beside gromp), where the aggro will "soft reset", cancelling the monsters'auto attacks without having them regain full health.

Best example would be Kikis'Twisted Fate jungle in IEM Semi-Final (

). They spent a lot of time watching him jungle, so you can learn from that.

Your clear speed depends on how much damages you're willing to take. When they reset, the monsters gain a bit of health back, so it might take a bit longer to clear camps. You have to tank them if you don't want them to reset, but you'll take more damages and won't be able to duel anyone.

So the answer to your question is **Yes, any adc can jungle**, with any runes/masteries, thanks to the monsters'way of resetting.

However, most of them aren't viable. Junglers usually can be sorted in 3 categories:

- Strong ganks thanks to their high damages (Lee, Khazix)
- Strong ganks thanks to their amount of crowd controls (Nautilus, Rammus)
- Weak ganks, but fast clear speed allowing them to get ahead of the opponent and reach a lategame stage faster (Master Yi, Tryndamere)

Of course some junglers stand between several categories, but viable junglers enter at least one of them.

Most AD carries have no crowd control, no damages early game, and their clear speed will be a lot slower than the likes of Shyvana or Yi.

The only ones that I would say are somewhat viable are Twitch (level 2 ganks with red buff are huge, devourer is also really good on him), or Vayne if you can get lucky on your first ganks top/bot (if you have a high damages laner and can manage to stun the opponent against the wall). I wouldn't recommend playing anyone else in a serious game.

Answer (score 4):

The only ADC that was ever viable for jungle in the first place was, and probably still is, Twitch. But he was never centered around efficient clearing and many jungler aren't. Ganking was his go to mechanism.

I'd recommend:

Grump(smite) -> Blue -> Wolves -> Wraith(smite) 

 Back

 Red

 Gank-> Situational

Runes: 

Flat AD Reds

50/50 Flat Armor Health Yellows

1 Flat AD Quint, 2 Flat AS Quints

50/50 AS / Scaling MR or CDR Blues

Items:

Purple jungle, Devourer (Here's your clearing potential)

Standard twitch: BOTRK, Yommus, Graves, IE, def item. 


A quick search on probuilds told me that some high-tier players still play it: http://www.probuilds.net/champions/Twitch

EDIT: You can actually play ranged junglers pretty well in season 5, due to the fact that you can almost completely negate buff-damage and some camps.

<- Watch how this guy does the camps.

Comment: I've also seen Vayne used in the jungle.

Comment: vayne, ashe ,....

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Ashe O_O

Comment: @Shunwoo it's like a squishy nunu without sunstain.... it's hard (and i wouldn't say it's viable)

Comment: If it was me, I'd either go all 3 AS quints and even some marks in AS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Released in October of 2015, [**Kindred**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kindred) are both a dedicated ranged ADC jungler. Their passive, Mark of the Kindred, marks targets to hunt:

> Scoring a takedown on a marked target permanently empowers Lamb's basic attacks to deal 1.25% of her target's current health as bonus on-hit physical damage, capped at 75 (+ 10 per stack) against monsters, stacking with each Mark consumed.

As a player, you may also select one opponent champion to have as a target at any one time. This has a cooldown. The targets marked by Wolf are neutral monsters and camps. This gives you plenty of motivation to play Kindred as a jungler, build up stacks, then dominate late game.

Their Q, Dance of Arrows, has a short cooldown and hits three targets at once. It works together well with their W, Wolf's Frenzy, which lowers Q's cooldown time. It used to heal Kindred, but that was removed since Kindred was becoming too powerful as a top-laner.